# How to get frequency counts on two variables in R?

Tags: r

I looking for a way to get a frequency count out of an R data frame based on two values. I've tried a few different syntaxes and I'm fairly new at R.

```
> table(frequency.data.frame$value,frequency.data.frame$value_x)[!is.na(frequency.data.frame$id),]
Error in `[.default`(table(frequency.data.frame$value, frequency.data.frame$value_x),  : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
> table(frequency.data.frame$value,frequency.data.frame$value_x[!is.na(frequency.data.frame$id),])
Error in frequency.data.frame$value_x[!is.na(frequency.data.frame$id),  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

Given

First dimension.

```
as.data.frame(table(frequency.data.frame[!is.na(frequency.data.frame$id),]$value))
   Var1 Freq
1     2    2
2     3    2
3     4    5
4     5   21
5     6    8
6     7   19
7     8   52
8     9   33
9    10   56
10   11    1
11   12    1
```

second dimension.

```
as.data.frame(table(frequency.data.frame[!is.na(frequency.data.frame$id),]$value_x))
   Var1 Freq
1     1   50
2     2   17
3     3   12
4     4    7
5     6   18
6     8    6
7     9    1
8    10   19
9    14    1
10   15    1
11   16   11
12   17    2
13   18    2
14   96    3
15   97    4
16   98   46
```

Data frame sample data extract...

```
> frequency.data.frame
                                  id name                                                           factor value value_x
1                               <NA>                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=1 - 1     1       1
2                               <NA>                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=2 - 2     2       1
3   e7f0940c64001d4ab9d43ebd1e361292                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=3 - 3     3       1
4                               <NA>                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=4 - 4     4       1
5   2de771a03f49ce72eb721159933d4827                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=5 - 5     5       1
6   307ad612c3cc9fe5741c1fe75d1bc217                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=5 - 5     5       1
7   522f594612678f13f9dd5ee8f4f24df7                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=5 - 5     5       1
8   c1c32ac37f572fb259fe4e454bbdf743                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=5 - 5     5       1
9   d5b784d8f9508da7ac9573b535fe7147                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=5 - 5     5       1
10  e07439cdc15377d209413b31d9f80056                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=6 - 6     6       1
11  878a67dbbb428c65c83602fc112a24a0                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=6 - 6     6       1
12  5f7c27fb104685c26e53fc3267024539                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=7 - 7     7       1
13  6b12a3591d89f7b70587406a0c4f92bb                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=7 - 7     7       1
14  7fb2f98867e0e100187f0b4f13baac46                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=7 - 7     7       1
15  99a0ffaa2066e5c4806f2e30a446a31f                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=7 - 7     7       1
16  9d214544e8eaf3ea9c416a3dfbddb9f6                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=7 - 7     7       1
17  b36f990b1e0d8c5f04a47d23b70c1022                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=7 - 7     7       1
18  f2f9395bd9ddc16acd2253bd114aca64                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=7 - 7     7       1
19  4420e8499ab32631b389111935314468                                        OSuppl=1 - Ardex | Imp_1=8 - 8     8       1
...
```

Desired result extract example

```
   Var2 Var1 Freq
...
6     5    1 5
7     6    1 2
8     7    1 7 
9     8    1 1
...
```

What sort of syntax would I need to get the example desired output?

Comment: You can `filter` based on 'id' first and then do a `table` i.e. `as.data.frame(table(subset(frequency.data.frame, select = c('value', 'value_x'), !is.na(id))))`

Comment: Many thanks @akrun. That works. Would you like to write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are only getting the frequency of 'value', 'value_x' based on the non-NA 'id', `subset` based on the non-NA elements, `select` the columns of interest, get the `table` and convert to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(table(subset(frequency.data.frame, 
             select = c('value', 'value_x'), !is.na(id))))
```

---

The `tidyverse` syntax for the above solution would be

```
library(dplyr)
frequency.data.frame %>%
        filter(!is.na(id)) %>%
        count(var1 = value, var2 = value_x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr)
counts <- ddply(frequency.data.frame, .(frequency.data.frame$value_x, frequency.data.frame$value), nrow)
names(counts) <- c("value_x", "value", "Freq")

      value_x value Freq
  1         1     1    1
  2         1     2    1
  3         1     3    1
  4         1     4    1
  5         1     5    5
  6         1     6    2
  7         1     7    7
  8         1     8   10
  9         1     9    9
  10        1    10   15
  11        1    11    1
  12        1    12    1
  13        2     1    1
  ...
```